# ArrayList Entity property mystery using 'Integer' objects

Tags: java, google-app-engine, arraylist

Why am I able to set an Entity property to ArrayList but not
ArrayList?

The below code works fine but when I change the 'Long' objects to 
'Integer' objects the Entities are constructed properly but when I
execute some code to edit an entity I get the error shown following
the sample code?

```
//  Fetch the Datastore Service instance [ds]...
DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
//
//  Initialize an Entity [row] for each ‘State Code’...
//
Key stateKey = null;    Entity stateEntity = null;
//  Zero Controls...
Long iZero = new Long(0);
ArrayList<Long> al = new ArrayList<Long>();
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {   al.add(iZero);  }
//  One Controls
ArrayList<Long> alDebug = new ArrayList<Long>();
Long iOne = new Long(1);    
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {   alDebug.add(iOne);  }
//   LOOP on 'stateCodes' String Array...
for (String code : stateCodes)      {
    stateKey = KeyFactory.createKey(numbersKind, code);
    stateEntity = new Entity(stateKey);
    if (    code.equals("AZ")   )   {
       stateEntity.setProperty("stateNumbers", alDebug);    }
    else                            {
        stateEntity.setProperty("stateNumbers", al);        }
    ds.put(stateEntity);
}   //  End 'stateCodes' LOOP...
//  Code to test Enity modifications...
//  Get Array List for "AZ"...
Key nStateKey = KeyFactory.createKey(numbersKind, "AZ");
stateEntity = new Entity(nStateKey);
try {
    Entity entityTest = ds.get(nStateKey);
    ArrayList<Long> alAZ =
        (ArrayList<Long>) entityTest.getProperty("stateNumbers");
    Long iTest = alAZ.get(2);    // LINE THAT INVOKES ERROR...
    alAZ.set(2, iTest+new Long(4935));
    ds.put(entityTest);
} catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
    out.println("Entity does not exist in the datastore...");  }
```

Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to 
   java.lang.Integer at 
      jFormTKServlets.JFormTKServletsServlet.doGet(
         JFormTKServletsServlet.java:330)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
...
```

Comment: Can you distill this code down to a smaller sample which demonstrates the same problem? This code is really hard to follow.

Comment: are you sure that this line causes the error?

Comment: And you 100% certain you're changing _all_ the relevant `Long`s to `Integer`s and `ArrayList<Long>` to `ArrayList<Integer>`?

Comment: Yes. I used the find/replace function of the Eclipse editor. Actually, I originally coded it using the Integer object. Once I could not understand the error I changed it to the Long object and it worked fine...

Also, when it was using the Integer object I put the "alAZ.get(2)" into a println statement and it showed the expected result but the "Integer iTest = alAZ.get(2)" still received the error...

Comment: I spent the morning changing the Entity Object to ArrayList<Short> and got the same error as when I had the Entity Object as ArrayList<Integer>. I also tried removing the ArrayList object, i.e. I set the Entity property to 'Short'. Again, the same error...<br>

My conclusion is that the "Entity entityTest = ds.get(nStateKey);
    ArrayList<Object> alAZ =
        (ArrayList<Object>) entityTest.getProperty("stateNumbers");" statement will always return a Long object during run time. I tried to "work Around" this but the compiler balks because it thinks that 'alAZ' is as I coded it...<br>

Comment: I am spending to much time on this and will use the Long for now. I may try using an encoded String in lieu of the ArrayList but that approach will up the server side processing time...

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Besides the fact that:

```
    ArrayList<Long> alAZ =
    (ArrayList<Long>) entityTest.getProperty("stateNumbers");
```

works or not,

```
 Long iTest = (long) a1ZA.get(2);
```

should get you the result you want if `a1AZ.get(2)` returns an `int`. :)

Comment: Note that the 'Long' object works fine, the 'Integer' object usage only causes the error...

I guess I can live with the 'Long' object usage but I was curious to see if I somehow caused this problem...